# change SQL query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

How do I change a certain SQL query form inside PHP code Like for example here in the below code

```
<?php
function eb_mine_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'statuser') {
    dsm($query, 'before');
    $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
    dsm($query, 'after');
  }
}
?>
```

this code is related to a Drupal modification.

previous query

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created
FROM 
{node} node
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index_value_0 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_0.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = :views_join_condition_0
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index_value_1 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_1.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = :views_join_condition_1
WHERE ((( (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_2) )**AND**( (taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_3) )))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

After the above code runs the resulting query

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created FROM node node OUTER JOIN taxonomy_index taxonomy_index_value_0 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_0.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = '9' OUTER JOIN taxonomy_index taxonomy_index_value_1 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_1.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = '6' WHERE ((( (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = '9') )OR( (taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = '6') ))) ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

As you can see the query changed from AND to OR.

Now I want to change the same code like this:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created FROM node node LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_index taxonomy_index_value_0 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_0.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = '9' LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_index taxonomy_index_value_1 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_1.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = '6' WHERE ((( (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = '9') )OR( (taxonomy_index_value_1.tid = '6') ))) ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

rather than using **OUTER JOIN** I want to use **LEFT OUTER JOIN**. So how do I do this in my PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function eb_mine_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'statuser') {
    dsm($query, 'before');
    $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
    $query->tables[1]['type'] = 'LEFT OUTER';
    dsm($query, 'after');
  }
}
?>
```